# How do I consider different options for different services in blueimp-file-upload-expressjs

Tags: node.js, web-services

This is part of my code :

```
var options1 = {
  tmpDir: __dirname + '/private/uploaded/tmp',
  uploadDir: __dirname + '/private/uploaded/files',
  uploadUrl: '/uploaded/files/',
  //
  //
  ////rest of the options
};

var options2 = {
  tmpDir: __dirname + '/../pingova/uploads/tmp',
  uploadDir: __dirname + '/../pingova/uploads/images',
  uploadUrl: '/../pingova/uploads/',
  //
  //
  //rest of the parameters
};

// inti the module
var moduleRequried = require('blueimp-file-upload-expressjs');

// init the uploader2
var uploader2 = moduleRequried(options1);

// init the uploader2
var uploader2 = moduleRequried(options2);

app.post('/upload-image', function(req, res) {
  uploader1.post(req, res, function(error, obj, redirect) {
    //here I am using uploader1
  });

});


app.post('/upload-profile-pic', function(req, res) {
  uploader2.post(req, res, function(error, obj, redirect) {
    //here I am using uploader2
  });

});
```

**Problem with the code is:**
***even though I have created separate options and initialised it, its storing the image at option 2***
I am not understanding how to provide different options. I want different options to store the images at 2 different file location

Comment: I solved it. I dont know if its the correct way. I placed
// init the uploader2
var uploader2 = moduleRequried(options1);

inside the post method

Comment: But I feel the above way I accepted is not so reliable. So if any one has some other solution, please mention it